# Set keyboard to stay open even on "go" press with html5/javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm building a small html5 web-app to hone my html5 skills. I've built the project and it works pretty good, but I want to enable some mobile functionality which should make it even cooler! One of the annoyances of using the site on mobile is that whenever you press the "go" button on the android keyboard after entering data into a textbox, it hides its self, despite the fact that in javascript I've specified that the textbox still has focus. Is there a way to explicitly tell the android browser to keep the keyboard open?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is beyond the realms of JS - The keyboard is part of android, and thus (I assume) would be up to the browser to decide whether the keyboard stays or not - how would you cope for different browsers running across android?

Because I would assume they're not all running Webkit (Firefox mobile?).

So I think the answer is it can't be done :(